# Return view of Action Result showing file download warning, calling controller from JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using `JQGrid` to call the controller method to execute. JQGrid column description are:

```
  colNames: ['Id', 'Operation Name', ''],
  colModel: [{ name: 'OperationID', index: 'OperationID', width: 10, align: 'left' },
       { name: 'OperationName', index: 'OperationName', width: 90, align: 'left' },
       { name: 'Execute', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl:'@Url.Action("ExecuteOperaion")' }, search: false}],
```

And controller is implementation of method:

```
    public ActionResult ExecuteOperaion(int id)
    {
        /// method calculation using switch case with id as case parameter..
        return Json(true,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now after executing I just want to show a messagebox that operation executed. But while returning this Json to ActionResult, it shows file download warning message.

Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: got reference that if "If there is no content type specified, it will download the content as a file.", so while returning Json it should return 

     Json("hello from JSON","text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

If there is no content type specified, it will download the content as a file.", so while returning Json it should

```
return Json("hello from JSON","text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```